# Setting Active Class on Bootstrap Radio Buttons with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I tried to generate radiobuttons in radioGroup using `ng-repeat` directive and buttons with checkbox behavior. How should  I do it correctly???

```
$scope.config = [{
  name: 'First',
  callEvent: 'setValue()'
}, {
  name: 'Second',
  callEvent: 'setValue()'
}, {
  name: 'Third',
  callEvent: 'setValue()'
}];
```

HTML

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <label ng-repeat="item in config" class="btn btn-primary classButton"
         ng-click="item.callEvent" ng-model="radioModel" 
         uib-btn-radio="'{{item.name}}'">{{item.name}}
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle so we can troubleshoot easily? Are you referencing a controller properly?  Tagging your HTML as an `ng-app`?  Referencing `angular.js` propertly? Etc?

Answer (score 1):

To call functions from items added by the `ng-repeat` directive, use `$index` as your calling argument. Bootstrap buttons use the `active` class to indicate selection. Use the `ng-class` directive to add `active` to the selected button's class.

```
<body ng-controller="test">
     <div class="btn-group">
          <label ng-repeat="item in config" 
                 class="btn btn-primary classButton" 
                 ng-class="config[$index].btnClass" 
                 ng-click="setActive($index)">
          {{item.name}}
          </label>
     <br> The active button is -- {{config[activeButton].name}}
     </div>
```

In your model controller:

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('test', function($scope) {
     $scope.config = [{
          name: 'First',
          btnClass: 'active'
     }, {
          name: 'Second',
          btnClass: ""
     }, {
          name: 'Third',
          btnClass: ""
     }];
     $scope.activeButton = 0;
     $scope.setActive = function setActive(index) {
         $scope.activeButton = index;
         for (var i = 0; i < $scope.config.length; i++)
               $scope.config[i].btnClass = "";
         $scope.config[index].btnClass = 'active';
    };
});
```

The code in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rv4QkSyXF3jljCbby6jc)